# Delete files after upload to PyPi

Tags: python, distutils, distribute, pypi

I'm uploadig my package to PyPi with this command:

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

This command generate some files and folders, is there any option to delete this files after upload?

Comment: That's contents of the package you are uploading, why do you even want to delete them?

Comment: I can use my code directly, in the package I just have duplicated code. After upload, I delete it manually.

Comment: Yes, but it almost always a good habit to save the packages you have made ready for distribution thus it will be easier to locating bugs and other possible issues, even though you use a VCS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sdist command calls the build command which by default puts files in a `build` subdirectory.  You probably want to keep that around (i.e. not care about it) to speed up future builds.

sdist then puts the distribution files in a `dist` subdirectory by default.  `python setup.py sdist -d $TMP` (or the `%something%` equivalent environment variable for Windows) can be used to put the file in a temporary directory instead, so that they’re wiped out at the next boot.

If you really care about the build dir, try this: `python setup.py build -b $TMP sdist -d $TMP`.  sdist should be clever enough to find the files created by build.

distutils docs: http://docs.python.org/distutils

command help: `python setup.py build --help`

Comment: I don't know why also a .egg-info folder is created. For the sdist is not used, to create this folder also in a tmp folder I added an option, my final command is: `python setup.py build -b $TMP egg_info -e $TMP sdist -d $TMP`

Comment: @JoséLuis Thanks for this comment. Funny that every build step has a different letter to specify the output directory.

Answer (score 1):

Log into PyPI, and click on your package in the gray box in the upper right corner of the screen. Click "files" in the list to the right of the appropriate version. That will load a new page. Check off the files you want to delete and click the gray "Remove" button.

Comment: This doesn't answer this question but it answered the question I had. Thanks.